# Any guidance on enum suffix (Kind vs. Type)?

Tags: c#, .net, api, naming-conventions

I am designing a .NET API for public use.  In my API, there are a bunch of enums, and I'm struggling to decide on a convention to use for suffixes.

In the .NET framework, I see examples of using both "Kind" (e.g. `System.DateTimeKind`) as well as "Type" (e.g. `System.IO.DriveType`).

Looking at the public enums in mscorlib, I see that "Type" is used more often, but both are still used on some of the newer types, meaning it looks like Microsoft is not following any specific convention on this.

Does anyone have any recommendation about what to use in my API?  Are there any published conventions out there covering this topic?

I'm leaning towards using "Kind" as the suffix, and reserving the term "Type" to deal with `System.Type` objects or data types.

Comment: Try to read you type aloud or if English is not a language you are confident in ask someone else to do that. Some objects/concepts are better with "Type" other with "Kind" or "Mode" or something completely different. The goal is to make code readable - writes sample usage and read it aloud...

Comment: `DateTimeKind` and `DateTimeType` both sound fine.  I'm not worried about how it sounds (I know how to make it sound right).  I just want consistency in my API.

Comment: In a sense, this is a duplicate of [What's the difference between “Kind” and “Type”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15075/15093). I think you can find some guidance there.

Comment: Forcing all/most enums (or other types) to have the same suffix may not improve redability of the code... On `DateTimeKind/Type` - I think both are relatively bad as there is no way for a person to know what kind of values to expect for such enumeration. But as timezones are not widely used concept in spoken language there is no particularly better alternative. And the more useful name `DateTimeTimezone` clashes with class that represents instance of the concept. (+1 to Rob Lyndon comment on trying to avoid either)

Comment: I think they probably use `Kind` rather than `Type` because type often refers to `System.Type`. StyleCop will complain if you use a `type` suffix in method a parameter name that is not a `Type`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only naming convention I know from Microsoft in relation to enumerations is this (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

> - Use Pascal case for Enum types and value names.
> - Use abbreviations sparingly.
> - Do not use an Enum suffix on Enum type names.
> - Use a singular name for most Enum types, but use a plural name for Enum types that are bit fields.
> - Always add the FlagsAttribute to a bit field Enum type.

It's quite old but don't see any update in relation to this.

I don't think anyone can tell you the "correct" approach for your specific question as both options are valid and it's just a matter of taste.

I'd say you should agree a common strategy with the team and stick with it. I think it's more important everyone to use the same naming convention than which one you use.

I personally use `Type` suffix, but again, it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

Name your enums with descriptive noun phrases describing what the enum **is** (e.g., `RegexOptions` , `DateTimeKind` , `BorderStyle`, etc.). Don't force the use of arbitrary suffixes. The name should come naturally from what the thing **is**.

Comment: yeah, but "Kind" and "Type" are pretty interchangeable.  I don't like APIs with two terms for the same thing.

Comment: The best advice is probably to avoid either. They both lack specificity, and fail to convey meaningful information. Sometimes your categories will be like that, being fairly abstract quantities, but you can usually use a more meaningful word, such as Method or Tier, as your suffix.